# HTML Parsing in web browsers?

Tags: html, parsing

I’m a beginner and I’m wandering for this question.
Right now I’m concerned with webkit (a web browser).
Here, my problem is, what I want to know, how the web browser is handling all the HTML data coming from any network.
E.g. how is it getting the data and parsing that?
Very specifically, I want to know about HTML Parser!
If you have the code base of webkit, you can find a part that’s webcore.
In webcore, there is a HTML module.
As I think, this is the part of HTML parser.
But it seems very tough for me to understand that code without knowing the basics.
So please help me.

Comment: Are you going to build your own webbrowser?

Comment: I’m no quite sure what you’re asking for. But a recent entry in [WebKit.org’s Surfin’ Safari Blog](http://webkit.org/blog/) is about how [How WebKit Loads a Web Page](http://webkit.org/blog/1188/how-webkit-loads-a-web-page/). Though, it’s not quite about parsing but rather about rendering.

Answer (score 4):

You would need some basic understanding on formal language definitions and compilers. Without this knowledge looking at the parser code for 1000 years is futile.

I recommend to read this book first:

[image]